# Garbage appears in vector after inserting result of operator

Tags: c++

I have an object with an operator defined like this:

```
P& operator +(const P &rhs) {
    return P(x + rhs.x, y + rhs.y, z + rhs.z);
}
```

It does not have custom copy or assignment operators.

After I assign directly the result of an addition inside the vector, garbage appears inside it.

```
P p1(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
P p2(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

vector<P> v(1);
v[0] = p1 + p2; // v[0] now contains garbage.
```

If I do it through a variable, everything is as expected.

```
vector<P> u(1);
P q = p1 + p2;
u[0] = q; // u[0] contains correct value.
```

What can be the reason for such behavior? What is the difference between the two cases?

Comment: "*It does not have copy or assignment operators.*" Do you mean that you didn't specifically define them (in which case the compiler is likely defining them implicitly)? Or that you went out of your way to disable them?

Comment: @ildjarn I meant to say that I did not specifically define them. Edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: The difference is the second example read from the invalid/deleted temporary _before_ it was overwritten.  (Both are against the rules, the temporary is dead)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You return a reference to a temporary. This is a bad idea, since the temporary goes out of scope at the end of the function (in this case, the `operator+` function). Declare your operator as:

```
P operator +(const P &rhs) const
```

instead.

Comment: That should be `P operator +(const P &rhs) const` -- as you have it, move semantics are inhibited.

Comment: I suspected that this is the issue, but why there is an problem only when I assign the result into a vector?

Comment: @Artium: Because the P is a local member of the `operator +` function, and was "deleted" as soon as the function ended.  If you then call another function, say, `insert`, then it will be erased with random data.

Comment: @Artium : That's the nature of [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) -- sometimes it may _appear_ to work, but it's never correct.

Answer (score 3):

As you would see

```
P& operator +(const P &rhs) 
{
    return P(x + rhs.x, y + rhs.y, z + rhs.z);
}
```

returns the reference to a local variable which is destroyed once out of scope of the function `operator +`.

You can return Pointer to the data created in heap but that would leave enough scope for Memory Leak if the caller fails to delete the object.

You can also return the object as a copy but that at times can be a real overhead

In recent C++11 use the move construct to transfer the ownership which should be the ideal and preferred approach going forward.

Comment: "*You can also return the object as a copy but that at times can be a real overhead*" Every modern compiler implements [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

Comment: @ildjarn: Seems I am bit outdated. :-)